# Excel switches formula language from dutch to English

Tags: excel

While working in my dutch oriented excel I regularly encounter a switch in formula language from Dutch to English.
Every other thing in my Excel looks dutch but the formulas are not recognized anymore, only English formulas seem to work.
I am using MS Excel 365 Version 2310, build 16924.20124
Language settings are set to Dutch, windows is also Dutch

[image]